# animate div on mouse hover and leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to animate listfrom left to right and vice versa,now i want  when mouse hover on div list animate left to right and when mouse leave that div than it list animate right to left , can anyone help me for this.

```
$('.ul_div').mouseover(function () {
    $('.ul_div').css({ display: 'block' });
    $('.ul_div ul').animate({ left: '100px', background: '#ccc' }, 100);
});
```

```html
<div class="ul_div">Hover Me<div>
<ul id='ulEle'>
    <li><a href="">demo</a></li>
    <li><a href="">demo</a></li>
    <li><a href="">demo</a></li>
    <li><a href="">demo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/HCP3L/1/)

Comment: FYI please include all code in your question. A link to a fiddle is great, but it will be useless if jsfiddle goes offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/HCP3L/2/)

**CSS:**

```
.ul_div ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none
}
.ul_div {
    border:2px solid Red;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.ul_div').hover(

 function () {
     $('.ul_div ul').css({
         display: 'block'
     });
     $('.ul_div ul').animate({
         left: '100px',
         background: '#ccc'
     }, 100);
 },

 function () {
     $('.ul_div ul').animate({
         left: '0',
         background: '#ccc'
     }, 100, function () {
         $('.ul_div ul').css({
             display: 'none'
         });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify positioning on the `ul` element in order to use the CSS `left` and `right` properties.

Update your CSS as follows:

```
#ulEle {
    position: absolute;
}

.ul_div {
    border:2px solid Red;
    position: relative;
}
```

You should then update your jQuery code to use the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function, and use the following code:

```
$('.ul_div').hover(function () {
    $('.ul_div ul').animate({ left: '100px', background: '#ccc' }, 100);
}, function() {  
     $('.ul_div ul').animate({ left: '0px', background: '#ccc' }, 100);
});
```

Please see the [<kbd>updated jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/HCP3L/3/) for a demo.